# About some difficulties in calculations

Tags: real-analysis, quadratics, real-numbers

I have an equation of the form:
$$f(x)=\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}a_{n}(x)=x^2+ax-1$$
where $x$ is a real number.
 that is, 
$$x^2+ax-1-f(x)=0$$
Solutions are: 
$$x=\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{a^2+4f(x)+4}-\frac{a}{2}$$ and 
$$x=-\frac{a}{2}-\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{a^2+4f(x)+4}$$ 
provided that:
$$a^2+4f(x)+4>0$$
I have two versions:
Replacing $f(x)$ by $x^2+ax-1$ to get $$a^2+4f(x)+4=a^2+4(x^2+ax-1)+4= (a+2x)^2>0$$
or replacing $f(x)$ by  $\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}a_{n}(x)$ to get $a^2+4f(x)+4=a^2+4+4\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}a_{n}(x)$
which is hard to decide if it is positive or not.

My question is: Is the first approach correct?

Comment: Grammar note: $f$ is a function, $f(x)$ is a number. Everywhere you've written $f$ alone, you mean $f(x)$. Or maybe you mean to introduce a new variable $y$ satisfying $y = f(x)$ and use $y$ everywhere.

Comment: @Hurkyl: Yes you are right. the equation is edited

Comment: You are running in circles. What exactly is the input to the problem, what the output? What is known about or demanded of the functions $a_n(x)$?

Comment: @LutzL: It is the term of the series defining $f$.

Comment: So this means that the $a_n$ as well as $a$ are the input? And you are looking for the solutions $x$ of the equation? Then your transformation leads to a fixed point formula where you now have to investigate if it is contractive. You could also use other methods as the bisection,secant or regula falsi methods to find roots in a more systematic way.

Comment: @LutzL: So, my first approach correct.

Comment: Yes, if something like convergence can be proven. Else this transformation is nice but useless. $-$ The condition $a^2+4f(x)+4\ge0$ only tells you that you need not look for solution where it is not satisfied. As nothing more concrete is provided about $f$, this is the most information you get out of that.

Comment: @LutzL: Thank you very much.